# need to increase storing capacity of a byte in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, byte

I have byte ...

```
Dim endframe As Byte
```

now i know that i can store a data value ranging from 0 to 255 in that byte. But I want to store it 0 to 500. can i do this? if yes then how can I achieve this?

Comment: You will have to choose a different data type then, for example `Short` or `Integer`.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to include what you are trying to accomplish.  There is no datatype that ranges from 0 to 500 - but there are certainly ones larger than that.  It's unlikely you need a 'large byte'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instead of *byte* type, use `System.Int16` (Short) [data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Use `StreamWriter or BinaryWriter` class methods to write data into the stream.

Comment: i mean to say will i get the same effect?

Comment: what i am actually doing is taking a value from a combobox and storing it in a file as a byte

Comment: What class/method you're using to save data into disk file?

Comment: i am using `FileStream.write` to save

Comment: @Drone: please update your question with what you are actually trying to do.